# Maximum number of partial waves and matching point

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

I have read that a large number of partial waves, around 200, are required in a situation such as ${}^{16}$O incident on ${}^{152}$Sm at c.m. 65 MeV in Coulomb excitation

Anybody familiar with scattering knows incoming partial waves are in units of angular momentum $L$, so $L \,= \,0, \, 1,\, 2$, etc are the incoming partial waves.

What exactly determines the maximum number of partial waves? Why is the matching distance taken at 300 fm?

Comment: The maximum partial wave L is determined by the S-matrix going to unity. In normal case( no couomb excitation) L = 70 is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows is a plot of magnitude of S-Matrix square against angular momentum L. When the coulomb excitatian potential is absent (No pot in legend) but only imaginary potential is present the matching diatance is irrlevant as long as it is away from the imag potential. This is clear from the dashed black curve and the red curve both coinciding. However in the presence of excitation potential matching point is important. Displayed by white curve (matching at 14.24 fm) and the black (curve matching at 38.24). Note however number of partial waves 101 is insuffecient since the black curve does not reach a magnitude of one. To check if the matching distance is ok one has to change the matching distance to higher values till one reproduces the result with lesser matching point. The value of strength of the coulomb excitation is slightly different from its actual since the work was carried for other system but put here.[image]

Comment: Esentially because the potential has a range longer than nuclear potential